# How to combine two more List<> parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have five different for web service

```
List<_FiltA> A= new List<_FiltA>();          
List<_FiltB> B= new List<_FiltA>();         
List<_FiltC> C= new List<_FiltA>();   
List<_FiltD> D= new List<_FiltA>();          
List<_MainFilt> Main= new List<_MainFilt>();
```

and 4 different method and 1 `[WebMethod]` for each list's parameters
For ex:

```
       [WebMethod]
           public List<_MainFilt> Search(string p1,int p2 ...)
            {
               Some code here...

             _FiltA= _FiltA(someParameters); //go to FiltA method
             _FiltB= _FiltB(someParameters);
                  .
                  .
                  some code...
                  .
                  .
              return Search;   //get Seach values
             }

           public List<_FiltA> FiltA (someParameters)
        {
           _FiltA FLG3 = new _FiltA();

             some codes....

              FLG3 = new _FiltA
                            {
                                PriceLink = Link,
                                Price = valueSomething,
                                Price2 = valueSomething1
                            };
                            Search.Add(FLG3);

           return FiltA ;

        }
```

And 3 more method like this.

I want to combined these 4 list (_ListA,_ListB,_ListC,_ListD) in `List<_MainFilt>` How can I combined? Or any suggestion for solving this problem?

Comment: How are the types `_FiltA` and `_MainFilt` related? In what way would you like to combine the lists? Do you want to concatenate them, or create new objects from the data in them?

Comment: Is _MainFilt a sub or super class of _FiltA? If only in these two cases you can do it easily, otherwise you need some convert method to convert from _FiltA to _MainFilt and use AddRange method to put them together

Comment: i want to add all list<> parameters value in _MainFilt,_MainFilt include all parameter which their have.  but it is not necessary it can be combined each list<> of their(_ListA,_ListB,_ListC,_ListD)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning `List<_MainFilt>`, you could return an object containing the 4 lists of filters, e.g:

```
public class Filters
{
  public List<_FiltA> FilterA {get; set;}
  public List<_FiltB> FilterB {get; set;}
  public List<_FiltC> FilterC {get; set;}
  public List<_FiltD> FilterD {get; set;}
}

...

[WebMethod]
public Filters Search(string p1,int p2 ...)
{
  return new Filters {
    FilterA = _FiltA(someParameters),
    FilterB = _FiltB(someParameters),
    FilterC = _FiltC(someParameters),
    FilterD = _FiltD(someParameters),
  };
}
```

Comment: i try but it says "_FiltA is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'" i declare all list in Filter class but it doesnt

Comment: i use Dictionary<> for SomeParameters it can be possible this err because of Dictionary<>

Answer (score 1):

You can just [concatenate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) them.

```
public List<_MainFilt> Search(string p1,int p2 ...) {
    var result = _FiltA(someParameters)
        .Concat(_FiltB(someParameters))
        .Concat(_FiltC(someParameters))
        .Concat(_FiltD(someParameters))
        .ToList();
    // Do something with the list...
}
```